# Function call on button added by eventContent in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

#### Calendar

[image: Calendar]

I am integrating full Calendar in Angular. I have added different events in full Calendar. On each event I have added button inside event. Where ever I click on the event , event click of full Calendar gets called. I want to call a function when user click on the button inside event content. Can someone assist me how can I do that.

Below is my code of button inside event of a full Calendar.

Comment: Can you be more specific .

Comment: I have attached the picture. In the picture I have button inside event and I want to call function on that button click in a full calendar

Comment: does my ans is what you are expecting

Comment: no . Sorry it is not what i am expecting.I simply want to call function when user click on evencontent of fullCalender

Comment: sorry ! I need an working snippet or more details about the design and java script function .. please edit the question

Comment: You'll need to add your current code before we can give you any more detailed help

Comment: P.s. what is the purpose of your specific button? Is there any reason you cannot simply trigger the same action via eventClick?

Answer (score 0):

If I really understand what you are asking for then ans is

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

### Snippet example

```js
function parent(event) {

console.log(alert("parent"))
}

function child(event) {

event.stopPropagation();

console.log(alert("child"))
}
```

```css
.parent{
  width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color: red;
 margin :auto ;


}
.child {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class = "parent" onclick = "parent(event)" >
<div class = "child" onclick = "child(event)">
 child
</div>

</div>
```